# django-models which field for asteriks *?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm setting up a database in Django.
Which is the correct field type for asteriks * in models.py? 
I have tried TextField, IntegerField and Charfield.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Task'

    save_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    hour_cr = models.TextField(default='*', validators=[MaxValueValidator(24), MinValueValidator(0)])
    minute_cr = models.TextField(default='*', validators=[MaxValueValidator(59), MinValueValidator(0)])
    day_of_the_month_cr = models.TextField(default='*', validators=[MaxValueValidator(31), MinValueValidator(0)])
    month_cr = models.TextField(default='*', validators=[MaxValueValidator(12), MinValueValidator(1)])
    day_of_week_cr = models.TextField(default='*', validators=[MaxValueValidator(7), MinValueValidator(1)])
    name_task = models.TextField(max_length=25)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'CharacterData'

Comment: What exactly you wanna do? Provide more information please!

Comment: Why are you saving a date time in (multiple) textfields?

Comment: I trying to make a cronjob generator.

Comment: Why not `CharField`?

Comment: I think that is working (have a other error, but thats is here not the subject). Thanks. I also had originally first * and now '*'.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, You just want a Type for putting `*` as data into it!

The best option is [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField)!

Also I see the other values the fields can get are integers!

Why don't you just use `-1` and then when you are using the model replace it with `*`?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm  newby: how do i give badges?

Comment: Just press on the tick next to the Answer and use the up vote button, uppon the votes count